# Angular SSR Serve Error NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppServerModule)[REQUEST]

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

I'm building with SSR in Angular, then I'm serving with SSR and I'm facing such an error. I have injected all services. I have injected all components.

**Error:**

```
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: StaticInjectorError(AppServerModule)[REQUEST]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[REQUEST]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for REQUEST!
    at NullInjector.get (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:18902:29)
    at resolveToken (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:30060:28)
    at tryResolveToken (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:30004:20)
    at StaticInjector.get (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:29906:24)
    at resolveToken (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:30060:28)
    at tryResolveToken (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:30004:20)
    at StaticInjector.get (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:29906:24)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:38371:33)
    at _createClass (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:38420:72)
    at _createProviderInstance (C:\Users\---\-----\dist\server\main.js:38388:30) {
  ngTempTokenPath: null,
  ngTokenPath: [ 'REQUEST' ]
}
```

**My app.server.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ServerCookiesModule } from 'ngx-universal-cookies/server';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UniversalInterceptor } from './universal.interceptor';
import { AuthenticationServerModule } from './authentication/authentication.server.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
    ServerCookiesModule.forRoot(),
    AuthenticationServerModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: UniversalInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to tell you how I solved the problem.

I added the following codes into the "server.ts" file. That's all.

server.ts :

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, {
    req,
    res,
    providers: [
      {
        provide: 'REQUEST',
        useValue: req,
      },
      {
        provide: 'RESPONSE',
        useValue: res,
      },
    ],
  });
});
```